# How to send soap request by python?

Tags: python, soap, zeep

I have soap reqest, and want to send it by python zeep script.

```
POST /IntegrationService/IntegrationService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.66.2
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <SendHardwareCommand xmlns="http://parsec.ru/Parsec3IntergationService">
      <sessionID>guid</sessionID>
      <territoryID>guid</territoryID>
      <command>int</command>
    </SendHardwareCommand>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I try to write it by myself

```
from pprint import pprint
from zeep import Client
CODE = '1'
LOGIN = 'PARSEC'
PASSWORD = 'pass'
client = Client('http://192.168.66.2:10101/IntegrationService/IntegrationService.asmx?wsdl', strict=False)

result = client.service.SendHardwareCommand(
    SendHardwareCommandRequest={'code': CODE, 'MessageType': 0},
    AuthorizationHeader={'login': LOGIN, 'password': PASSWORD})
pprint(result)
```

How to do it right?

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: TypeError: {http://parsec.ru/Parsec3IntergationService}SendHardwareCommand() got
 an unexpected keyword argument 'AuthorizationHeader'. Signature: `sessionID: {h
ttp://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/}guid, territoryID: {http://microsoft.com/wsdl/ty
pes/}guid, command: xsd:int`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

solved by requests

```
    import requests

territoryid = "91329321-12939213-9-32139-9123"


endpoint = "http://192.168.66.2:10101/IntegrationService/IntegrationService.asmx?wsdl"
user = "opendoor"
password = "password"

body="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
    <OpenSession xmlns="http://parsec.ru/Parsec3IntergationService">
        <domain>SYSTEM</domain>
        <userName>{user}</userName>
        <password>{password}</password>
    </OpenSession>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"""
body = body.format(user=user, password=password)
body = body.encode('utf-8')
session = requests.session()
session.headers = {"Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"}
session.headers.update({"Content-Length": str(len(body))})
response = session.post(url=endpoint, data=body, verify=False)

x=response.content
x=str(x,"UTF-8")
sessionid=x[ x.index("<SessionID>")+11 : x.index("</SessionID>") ]

body="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap12:Body>
    <SendHardwareCommand xmlns="http://parsec.ru/Parsec3IntergationService">
        <sessionID>{sessionid}</sessionID>
        <territoryID>{territoryid}</territoryID>
        <command>1</command>
    </SendHardwareCommand>
    </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>"""
body = body.format(sessionid=sessionid, territoryid=territoryid)
body = body.encode('utf-8')
session = requests.session()
session.headers = {"Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"}
session.headers.update({"Content-Length": str(len(body))})
response = session.post(url=endpoint, data=body, verify=False)

x=response.content
x=str(x,"UTF-8")

print("-------------------------")
#print (x)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')
if soup.find_all('Result', text='0'):
print ("door opened")
else:
print("door not opened")
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the structure of the `Header` in your xml and I can't test on the WSDL you provided but you may need to pass in your `login` and `password` values to the `_soapheaders()` kwarg in your service call:

```
# soap_call.py

from pprint import pprint
from zeep import Client
CODE = '1'
LOGIN = 'PARSEC'
PASSWORD = 'pass'
client = Client(
    'http://192.168.66.2:10101/IntegrationService/IntegrationService.asmx?wsdl', 
    strict=False
)

authHeaderRef = client.get_type('<namespace>:AuthorizationHeader')
authHeaderVals = authHeaderRef(login=LOGIN, password=PASSWORD)

result = client.service.SendHardwareCommand(
    _soapheaders={AuthorizationHeader=authHeaderVals},
    SendHardwareCommandRequest={'code': CODE, 'MessageType': 0})

pprint(result)
```

More about `_soapheaders` [here](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/headers.html).